# Creating NER model with Keras and Python

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I have made Keras model that detects if string value is Address, Company or Date. I have used only different company names, different date formants, and different street addresses for training.
So each row in my dataset have between 1 and 5 words (some words can be numbers).

For preprocessing I have used vectorizers:

```
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector char', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3, 6), max_features = 2000), 'text'),
                                                        ('vector word', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 4000), 'text')],
                                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns


features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)
```

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = features.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(200, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

I have achieved accuracy of 93%.
Is it possible to use that model for detecting where is that string (Address, Company or Date) in bigger text? I think that that kind of models is called NER models (named entity recognition).

My model takes string input and decides if its a company, person or address.
String input is 1-5 words long.

For example if I have text:

```
text = "What do you think about Amazon and their customer policy?"
```

How can I detect start index and end index of "Amazon", or how can I extract only Amazon from this text?
So required result should be:

```
start_index = 21
end_index = 27
```

Or:

```
result = {'company':'Amazon'}
```

Or for example if the input is:

```
"My name is Don John and I work in Amazon Inc."
```

as a result i want: `{"company": "Amazon Inc", "name": "Don John"}`

I want to use my model to extract specific entities from text, in this case company, address or date.
Basically I need some kind of `location search` thats based on Keras model, or searching for the pattern in large text.

Comment: What have you tried ? Are you looking for information as to how to reuse your trained model ? What is your keras model doing ? What is its input ? What is its output ?

Comment: My model takes string input and decides if its a company, person or address.
String input is 1-5 words long. I want to input much longer text, for example 1000 words, and to get location of company in text, or address etc

Comment: What prevents you to input a string with more than 5 words ? Is there an error ?

Comment: I can add a string of 100000 words, but results wont show or list all entities/words/phrases that are in that text.
For example If i enter the sentence "My name is Don John and I work in Amazon Inc.", as a result i want: {"company": Amazon Inc, "name": Don John}

Comment: Do you mean that the model you trained is a classifier that outputs the probability that the input is an Address, a Company or a Name ? And you want a way to apply this model to every words/n-gram in a sentence ?

Comment: yes, and to extract company address or person from text

Comment: Well you can compute the ngrams of your text and then apply your model on each one. Though I feel like a lot of NER systems use sequence labelling (with BIO labels) rather than classification..

Answer (score 1):

You can go two ways:

1. Use your current model. Split your long text into 3-5 words chunks (may be with some overlap of 1-2 words), then run your classifier on each chunk. As you move your window over the text, you will get an indication if the current chunk includes the entity you are searching for. This way you will be able to reconstruct the index of the word that triggered the entity classifier.
2. train your own NER. Then for each (sub)word you will get a classification. It is relatively easy. Use Huggingface's `transformers` library. You can base your code on [this post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/named-entity-recognition-for-turkish-with-bert-f8ec04a31b0) (they train Turkish NER). If you don't have access to GPU, you can use Google Colab for free. If running Transformer model is computationally  too expensive for you, you can try to go with CRF model. It will provide a bit lower performance, but should be faster. Refer to [this example](https://www.nexsoftsys.com/articles/overview-of-named-entity-recognition-using-crf.html).

To train your own NER with BERT, you need a labeled dataset. Usually it is a set of sentences in which every word is labeled (e.g. ORG, PERSON, etc.) Then you tokenize your sentence - convert text into (sub)words. The tokenizer is also provided within Huggingface library.

Then you fine-tune BERT on your dataset. The process is called fine tuning because BERT model is pretrained on vast amounts of data, and you only tune it for your task. Otherwise it is a regular supervised training process: you show a sequence of tokens and their labels to the model and try to minimize overall error. As a result each token will get some label.

In context of BERT models family NER is considered a token classification task (as opposed to text sequence classification and range detection). Usually BERT based NER perform very well. Here another [post](https://gab41.lab41.org/how-to-fine-tune-bert-for-named-entity-recognition-2257b5e5ce7e) on the process.

Comment: How to train my own NER? PS Your link does not work

Comment: I have tried to split the text to ngrams, but  I do not get very good results. Sometimes company name have 1 word sometimes 4 words, the same is for address and name.

Comment: I've fixed the link. You can get a fast evaluation of the BERT-based NER using [pipelines](https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER). Less than 10 lines of code! Their model does not include recognition of dates, but you will get an idea of what you can achieve on your dataset and  how fast it will work. As a bonus you don't require GPU for inference (only for training)